# Meteor and React Native

Tags: meteor, react-native

We're new to Meteor and would appreciate some advice. Currently we're building out an app for our client using **React Native**.

Does Meteor include / provide an 'offline first' capability via its API (in a React Native dev environment) ? So for example user can persist data on device (iOS/Droid) when offline and then when back online, it can be sync'd back to Meteor's cloud db (also handling sync update conflicts on server side correctly) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been directed to this issue, to get latest info on offline w/ Meteor via the react-native-meteor lib. Posting here if others are looking for same at the current time: https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-meteor/issues/154

Answer (score 0):

ok i got the best thing for you, i guess:

[react-native-meteor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-meteor)